# 2d array maps with if statements c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, 2d

I am working on a program that produces a map. In my print map function, I am taking in a boolean as a parameter. So if showTreasure is true, then the treasure will print out and vice versa. I have to print characters out on my map though. T for treasure at the end, S for start throughout the whole program, X for a place that the player has visited, and P for where the player currently is. If none of those apply, it prints a star. I figured out how to do the treasure and the star, but I can't seem to get the other three to work. Here is what I have:

```
// Cell types - The Map can have any of these
// characters at a location on a Map.
const char START = 'S';
const char PLAYER = 'P';
const char TREASURE = 'T';
const char EMPTY = '*';
const char VISITED = 'X';
```

Print Map function:

```
// Name: PrintMap
// Description: Prints the Map as shown in example
//      program output on assignment page.
// Return: Nothing
// ---------------------------------------------------
void PrintMap(const char Map[][COLS], const bool showTreasure, int &TreasureR, int      &TreasureC,
          int &StartR, int &StartC, int &Row, int &Col)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
       {

           if ((row == TreasureR && col == TreasureC) && showTreasure == true)
               cout << TREASURE;
           else if ((row == StartR && col == StartC) && showTreasure == true)
               cout << START;
           else
               cout << EMPTY;
       }
     cout <<  endl;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moin,

just wondering why you passed the `const char Map[][COLS]`but didn't use it.
Simply print the value of `Map[row][col]` under the condition that `showTreasure` is true.
Then you won't need the extra `int&` parameters.

Greez Alnjeno

Comment: I also don't know how to say that a location has been visited by the player.

Comment: what is stored in Map? 
maybe you can use bit-ops to add a flag to `char` value